# iOS Simulator "could not find the SDK" and it "may need to be reinstalled"

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I tried running my app today using Xcode 4.6.1 in the iPhone 6.1 simulator, however it did not work. The app built successfully but then when the simulator opened it said "iOS Simulator could not find the SDK. The SDK may need to be reinstalled." When this happened, I went to Xcode> Preferences>Downloads and it said the iOS 6.0 simulator was installed. I decided I would give the app a try in a different simulator so I installed the iOS 5.1 simulator, however the same exact message came up again. Could someone please help me solve this?

Thank you in advance and I really appreciate it.

Comment: How about doing what it suggests? Reinstall Xcode.

Comment: There are a lot of questions about this already [here's one of them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092452). One of the common issues seems to be having the "Target SDK" set to a version not installed.

Comment: Reboot, run disk verify, permission repair, etc. Do you have free space on your drive?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your dock icon not pointing to:

> Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app

Try launching the simulator from that directory or deleting Xcode and reinstalling from the Mac App Store as @cjc343 preposed.